# (Though?)Expression Rearranging

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, taylor-expansion, quadratic-forms

I have the following expression

$
2x+3x^2+e^{5x+x^2}=7
$

which I need rearranged in a form of the type $Ye^Y=Z$ with Y a function of x and Z some constant.
I have tried the substitution $y=5x+x^2$, that is I replaced x by the roots of that equation. For the root $x=\frac{-5+\sqrt{25+4y}}{2}$ I get

$e^y+11\sqrt{25+4y}+4y+38=0$

and I don't see how to get to the above mention form from here. Any idea about how I should tackle this? I don't know if the Taylor expansion of the exponential could help, can you see any link.Thank you.

Comment: "Y a function of x and Y some constant" Is one of these supposed to be Z?

Comment: fixed , thanks.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Are you sure you want $y(x)e^{y(x)}$ and not something like $y(x)e^{u(x)}$?

Comment: I do need $y(x)e^{y(x)}$ but if you can do $y(x)e^{u(x)}$ that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z=7$ and consider $y=W(2x+3x^2+e^{5x+x^2})$ where $W$ is a Lambert Omega function. In general you have $y=W(2x+3x^2+e^{5x+x^2}-7+Z)$ where $z$ is just a chosen number. I don't see any simplification after this point.

Comment: That's the whole point of the question, bringing the equation into the form that allows for the use of Lambert W to find its roots, so having the above substitution is not exactly what I need. How would you find the roots afterwards (other than numerically)?

Comment: So very simply if you are looking for $y$, that is given in the answer. I cannot simplify it and I dont think that someone can give a simple closed form simplification to that form and there is no other $y$ either. So what are you looking for? for $y$ or something else?

Comment: I am looking for y, but my final goal is to find those x that are roots of the above equation.

Comment: your work about the substitution is of no use. It doesn't simplify anything at all. Finding the roots of that equation is eqivalent to solve the omega term given in the answer. There is no closed form solution for those equations at least to my knowledge.

Comment: so, basically what you mean is that I have to compute W numerically?

Comment: I think one can do a bit more than that. Your problem is stated here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations with no solution. But in the same page there is also a taylor series expansion of W function around $0$ or $r$. In your case there is apolynomial term instead of simply $x$. What I would personally do is to obtain it numerically. Then find an MMSE polynomial solution to the numeric function.